# Designing Android Themes

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how I can change my apps theme from the default ones made available? Holo and Holo.Light get a bit boring after a while.

The likes of Facebook, Google+, BBC Weather, Viber, Vine and Twitter all look very professional and have their own theme whereas the app I'm developing looks quite boring.

Is it possible to change the font of the text in my app? I know it's possible to change the colour and size of it.

Another thing which would be useful to know would be how to change the colour of the action bar that is used for my app. Currently it's black but I wouldn't mind changing it to a different colour than those used by the Android default themes (e.g. purple, green, blue, etc)

Maybe you can share some tips on what you think works well for Android design?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question; moreover most of this stuff can be easily found via a cursory Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a custom theme at http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

If you only want to change a few font an colors etc take a closer look at this (source:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

If you like a theme, but want to tweak it, just add the theme as the parent of your custom theme. For example, you can modify the traditional light theme to use your own color like this:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

(Note that the color needs to supplied as a separate resource here because the android:windowBackground attribute only supports a reference to another resource; unlike android:colorBackground, it can not be given a color literal.)

Now use CustomTheme instead of Theme.Light inside the Android Manifest:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```